# AggregateRating Schema: Mixed Validation Results

Tags: validation, markup, schema.org, google-search-console, bing-webmaster-tools

We use schema.org to markup a number of different data types. I have typically relied on the Google testing tool to confirm that my schema is correct, but I've found that I get mixed results when testing with Bing, Yandex, Linter and MOZ.

Currently my 'aggregaterating' schema appears valid in Google's tester, but I get no results on Bing (can't find the markup) and Yandex/Linter both show errors. This makes me wonder if my schema is actually correct.

This was my original version which was OK on Google but got no results (no data found) on any of the other testers.

```
<div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/AggregateRating">
<meta itemprop="itemReviewed" content="https://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
<meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4.6">
<meta itemprop="reviewCount" content="3,950">
</div>
```

This is my updated version that now, at least partially, is seen by Linter and Yandex. I still get nothing from MOZ and Bing.

```
<div itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization">
<meta itemprop="name" content="Company">
<div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/AggregateRating">
<meta itemprop="itemReviewed" content="https://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
<meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4.6">
<meta itemprop="reviewCount" content="3,950">
</div></div>
```

Any feedback on the format? Something I am missing? Also, has anyone else had the mixed validation issue with other testers? I find that really odd.

Comment: What is this MOZ thing, do you have a URL? And the Bing tool you used is not usable without an account, right?

Comment: The MOZ toolbar (Chrome Extension) has a page analysis that specifies if it finds any marked up data. And, yes, for Bing the markup tester is within their Webmasters portal.